# How many one-to-one functions are possible from A to B where |A| = 4 and |B| = 6 such that ith element of A can not be macthed with ith element of B?

Tags: combinatorics

I used the principle of inclusion-exclusion for solving this. I want to know if my solution is correct.
The answer for the problem will be given by:

$Total\;into\;functions - Functions\; with\; 1 \;incorrect\; match + Functions \;with\; 2\; incorrect\; matches - Functions \;with \;3 \;incorrect\;matches + Functions \;with \;4\; incorrect\; matches$

Answer $= \binom{6}{4}4! - \binom{4}{1}5*4*3 + \binom{4}{2}4*3 - \binom{4}{3}3 + \binom{4}{4}$

Answer $ = 360 - 240 + 72 - 12 + 1 = 181$

Comment: For what it's worth, you're counting [derrangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

Comment: Yes but in that problem both sets have the same cardinalities, right?

Comment: Ah, right, and I don't see a quick way to get from one answer to the other